# Multiple buttons in html, same view, different values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to have my html display a session.counter on an HTML page. The counter should increment by a random number, with 4 different options for the range at which it increments (based on buttons). So far, I have all their actions routing to the same view, but I'm not sure how to code the values into the view! Can I nest multiple if-checks into the view? If so, do I need to redirect immediately after each check, or can it be after the if-checks?
EDIT: I've tried adding hidden inputs to make my view more efficient. I'm still a novice, so if the more descriptive your feedback, the easier it will be for me to implement changes and understand why!

Here's the html:

```
        <div id="goldCount">
    <h2>Gold Count: {{ session.request.goldCount }}</h2>
</div>

<div id="goldNode">
    <h2>Blood Lotus Master</h2>
    <h5>(earns 50 to 200 gold coins)</h5>
    <form action='/process_gold' method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="earn" value="reap">
        <button type="submit" name="reap">収める - Reap</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="goldNode">
    <h2>Shadow Dance Troupe</h2>
    <h5>(earns 35 to 50 gold coins)</h5>
    <form action='/process_gold' method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="earn" value="weave">
        <button type = "submit" name = "weave">織る - Weave</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="goldNode">
    <h2>Necromancy</h2>
    <h5>(earns -200 to 200 gold coins)</h5>
    <form action='/process_gold' method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="earn" value="summon">
        <button type = "submit" name="summon">召喚 - Summon</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="goldNode">
    <h2>Clan War!</h2>
    <h5>(earns -2000 to 2000 gold coins)</h5>
    <form action='/process_gold' method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="earn" value="summon">
        <button type="submit" name="war">影の戦争 - Shadow War</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

### and here is the views.py file

```
    def index(request):
if 'goldCount' not in request.session:
    request.session['goldCount'] = 0
return render(request, 'index.html')

    def process_gold(request):
reap = random.randint(50,200)
weave = random.randint(35,50)
summon = random.randint(-200,200)
war = random.randint(-2000,2000)

print(request.POST)

if request.POST['earn'] == 'reap':
    request.session['goldCount'] += random.randint(50,200)

if request.POST['earn'] == 'weave':
    request.session['goldCount'] += random.randint(35,50)

if request.POST['earn'] == 'summon':
    request.session['goldCount'] += random.randint(-200,200)

if request.POST['earn'] == 'war':
    request.session['goldCount'] += random.randint(-2000,2000)

return redirect('/')
```

Comment: The code you posted will not work (goldCount is not defined before use). Also assigning values to `request.POST` in a view makes no sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm a novice, so the more explanation you can offer - the better I can implement the changes and improve my code! I was told that using a hidden field, but I've never done it before (still giving it a shot tho). How would you suggest fixing the posted code, stefanw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send `goldCount` through to HTML you need to use a render_template rather than a redirect.  Store the `goldCount` into session then just call `{{request.session.goldCount}}` in your HTML.

Also, the correct if statement would be:

```
if 'goldCount' not in request.session:
    request.session['goldCount'] = 0
```

Comment: Worked so far, but now my html isn't displaying my goldCount! I'm updating the code above to reflect changes!